# Class Based View - conditional redirect based on form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to redirect the user to different pages (and different forms) , when the user fills out the first form (stating whether they have an online account or not) in a view and clicks submit.

I have tried this via the below but I get SupplyTypeForm has no attribute cleaned_data

```
class ServiceTypeView(FormView):
    form_class = SupplyTypeForm
    template_name = "supplier.html"
    success_url = '/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super()
        online_account = self.form_class.cleaned_data['online_account']
        if online_account:
            redirect('../online')
        else:
            redirect('../offline')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this logic in the `form_valid` method, which recieves the form as an argument. Note you need to *return* the value of the call to render, and your call to `super()` on its own does nothing; you have to reference a method on that object.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    super().form_valid(form)
    online_account = form.cleaned_data['online_account']
    if online_account:
        return render(request, "supplier_online.html")
    else:
        return render(request, 'supplier_offline.html')
```

Comment: thanks. i get a unresolved ref error with request for some reason?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you get an error, please post the full message and traceback.

Comment: Hmm it may just be the ide (pycharm) incorrectly highlighting an issue with request. The error I get is no URL to redirect to, provide a success_url. Do I need to override get_success_url too?  Doesn't the render(request, 'supplier_online.html;) take care of that?

Comment: You probably need to remove the super call completely, in fact. The thing is that you are not redirecting, as normally recommended after a POST, but simply rendering a response.

Comment: Sorry that should have been redirect not render, my mistake.  I still get the url not specified error.  should I be overwriting get_success_url too?

Comment: if I add success_url = '/' it works.  Not entirely sure why? Does the redirect just append the route to the success_url? Can you expand your answer to cover this and I can then accept.  Thanks.